# How to do validation check on unique composite key

Tags: hibernate, validation, jpa, playframework

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "field1", "field2"}))
public class A extends Model{

  public String field1;
  public String field2;
}
```

I would like to define my own check constraint by extending **play.data.validation.Check** so I can display a custom validation message.

However it seems that Check only applies to one field.
Is there another way to do this validation check on multiple fields?

**UPDATE - Solution**

```
 @Entity
 @Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "field1", "field2"}))
 public class A extends Model{

      @CheckWith(UniqueFieldsCheck.class)
      public String field1;
      public String field2;

    static class UniqueFieldsCheck extends Check {
        public boolean isSatisfied(Object obj, Object o) {
            boolean satisfied = true;
            A a = (A)obj;
            A aA = A.find("byField1AndField2", a.field1, a.field2).first();

            if (aA != null) {
                setMessage("This fields should be unique.");
                satisfied = false;
            }

            return satisfied;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well no, Play only let's you validate on each field individually. However you can make you own composite field, that's contained in a separate class and add it to you main object, something like:

```
public class A extends Model{

  @CheckWith(value = UniqueUserCheck.class, message = "error.not.unique")
  public ComplexField complexField;
}

public class ComplexField {

  public String field1;
  public String field2;

}
```

and then apply a custom validator to it (more on those [here](http://ronaldharing.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/validations-for-the-play-framework/))

Answer (score 1):

Using the JPA annotations will make sure that you cannot put the bad data into the database but not strictly speaking validation. You would just get an exception.

I would have a look at Hibernate Validator. It allows single field validation out of the box and you can implement your own annotations to perform more complex scenarios. It is also the reference implmenetation of Bean Validation JSR-303.

http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html

Comment: I don't think you can add Hibernate Validation library to a Play project. http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/83b0cc3996aacdcc?pli=1